# Print last nth columns on line

Tags: awk, aix

How can I print the last 4 columns using awk?

The following solution works fine with numbers:

Command:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | awk '{print $(NF-3),$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5
```

However, when I use text with special characters like below, I get a syntax error:

```
echo "2023-01-03 01:05:06:       Table test completed      (0 hrs 0 mins 0.009 Secs)" |  awk '{print $(NF-3),$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'
```

Output:

```
> " | awk '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'
mins 0.009 Secs)
awk: The field -2 cannot be less than 0.

The input line number is 2.
The source line number is 1.
```

What I am expecting to print out is the below for the above example:

```
(0 hrs 0 mins 0.009 Secs)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, the result of the command was `0 mins 0.009 Secs)` which are the last four fields (space-separated parts) of the input line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be: Using `match` function of `awk`. Using regex `\(.*\)$` which will match string from `(` to till `)` if match is found then printing sub-string which will print only matched value(s) as per OP's requirement.

```bash
echo "2023-01-03 01:05:06:       Table test completed      (0 hrs 0 mins 0.009 Secs" |
awk 'match($0,/\(.*\)$/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** If your Input_file always has "Table test completed" then you can make it more easy then 1st solution, try following then:

```bash
echo "Your_string" |
awk -F'[[:space:]]+Table test completed[[:space:]]+' '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another awk approach that splits a record using 2+ whitespaces:

```bash
echo "2023-01-03 01:05:06:       Table test completed      (0 hrs 0 mins 0.009 Secs)" |
awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' '{print $NF}'

(0 hrs 0 mins 0.009 Secs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this, clear unwanted fields and print string:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5" | awk '{$1=""   ; print}'
 2 3 4 5
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5" | awk '{$1=$2=""; print}'
 3 4 5
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5" | awk '{$3=$5=""; print}'
1 2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

either the `RS` way or the `FS` way :

```
echo "2023-01-03 01:05:06:       Table test completed" \
     "      (0 hrs 0 mins 0.009 Secs)"                  |
```

> ```
>  gawk   8   RS='^[^(]+' ORS=   # only suitable if input is known 
>                                #               to be 1 line only
>
>  mawk NF=NF FS='^[^(]+' OFS=   # preferred approach
> ```

```
(0 hrs 0 mins 0.009 Secs)
```